# how to pass null values as arguments from java to python

Tags: java, python

I have a java method that passes some arguments to a python file. I am passing the the arguments this way :

```
String name=null;  //can be null or some value in some cases.
....
String[] cmd = {
                      "python",
                      "C:/Python34/myscript.py",
                      name,
                      username,
                      pwd};
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

the variable name would be null in some execution and it might not but when it becomes null i am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

My python file `myscript.py` will run with null values if i am running it from command prompt but i am not able to from java.

How can i pass null value without the exception. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I think you're just supposed to pass nothing in if you want python to recognise it as null

Comment: Why cannot you define it as String name='' (empty string)

Comment: Make a distinction between nulls and empty strings. Most script-based languages would accept an *empty string* in an argument, but their concept of NULL usually doesn't apply to command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since python and java are different processes you are communicating between using system calls, you cannot convert Java `null` to the command line.

(What you call `null` in Python is actually `None`)

What you can do is: pass empty string (`""` not `null`) to the python program, and the python program can interpret empty strings and convert them to `None`.

Or decide a convention: if `"<NULL>"` string is passed from java then assume `None` from python side when parsing the args.

Other solutions like Jython would maybe allow this because they do no involve system calls.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing them as null, do a NullPointer check and pass in empty strings.

```
name = name == null ? "" : name;
```

That way your python script will just need to check for empty strings instead of nulls. And you can check for both by a simple if check. Something like below will work.

```
if not name:
    # this will check for both None and "" empty string
    print "name was not passed"
```